# How can one display an image using cv2 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I've been working with code to display frames from a movie. The bare bones of the code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read single frame avi
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('singleFrame.avi')
rval, frame = cap.read()

# Attempt to display using cv2 (doesn't work)
cv2.namedWindow("Input")
cv2.imshow("Input", frame)

#Display image using matplotlib (Works)
b,g,r = cv2.split(frame)
frame_rgb = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
plt.imshow(frame_rgb)
plt.title('Matplotlib') #Give this plot a title, 
                        #so I know it's from matplotlib and not cv2
plt.show()
```

Because I can display the image using matplotlib, I know that I'm successfully reading it in.

I don't understand why my creation of a window and attempt to show an image using cv2 doesn't work. No cv2 window ever appears. Oddly though, if I create a second cv2 window, the 'input' window appears, but it is only a blank/white window.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you read the docs?  Try `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow..`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are doing it almost good. There is one thing missing:

```
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So probably your window appears but is closed very very fast.

Answer (score 25):

you can follow following code

```
import cv2
# read image 
image = cv2.imread('path to your image')
# show the image, provide window name first
cv2.imshow('image window', image)
# add wait key. window waits until user presses a key
cv2.waitKey(0)
# and finally destroy/close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I think your job is done then

Comment: This is the correct approach. The accepted one might sometimes kill your jupyter kernel if working with notebooks.

Answer (score 16):

Since OpenCV reads images with BGR format, you'd convert it to RGB format before pass the image to pyplot

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('YOUR_FILEPATH')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is not what the writer is asking for. You are showing how to show a picture in matplotlib, while the question is about cv2.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30374756)

Comment: While not direclty related to the question this was useful to resolve a different error that I had.

Comment: For such comment as "This is not what the writer is asking for",  providing an alternative solution adds values. No need to be too stringent to reject valuable answers like this one.

Answer (score 6):

While using Jupyter Notebook this one might come in handy

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# reading image
image = cv2.imread("IMAGE_PATH")

# displaying image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `"Image"` should be removed. The first argument only accepts array-like values or PIL images.

Answer (score 4):

```
import cv2

image_path='C:/Users/bakti/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/resized_mejatv.jpg'

img=cv2.imread(image_path)

img_title="meja tv"

cv2.imshow(img_title,img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Collab then use the following two lines:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

cv2_imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Jupyter notebook, matplotlib may not display the image at its full scale.
I found that `display` in conjunction with PIL Image works better.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img_bgr = cv2.imread("path/to/image")  # array in BGR format
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # BGR -> RGB
img = Image.fromarray(img_rgb)  # convert to PIL image
display(img)
```